# jQuery changing HTML of DIV not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div at the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="stickyplayer">Loading..</div>
```

And elsewhere in the same page:

```
<a onclick="$('#stickyplayer').html('Foobar')" href="javascript:void(0);">Select</a>
```

Clicking on the link does nothing. A

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stickyplayer').html('Foobar');
});
```

does not work either.

jQuery is indeed included in the page. What is the problem here?

Comment: You know the problem must be somewhere else.. Not in what you have shown.

Comment: Code works fine, I have created a fiddle using it: http://jsfiddle.net/eRgrf/ perhaps you can check out the console log for errors?

Comment: yes, I am agree with @MichalKlouda it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

It works fine:

```
<div id="stickyplayer">Loading..</div>

<a onclick="$('#stickyplayer').html('Foobar')" 
href="javascript:void(0);">Select</a>
```

You may be missing the reference of the `js` file:

```
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can check here **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxgus/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your code and with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

work correctly ...

Indeed with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stickyplayer').html('Foobar');
});
```

also changed the value of the div when the page was ready

Hope you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code works. Perhaps you placed the items in the wrong place or have any interference with other code.